# Is it possible to use coolers/fans as wind powered generators?

Tags: generator

Is there a way to make a fan/cooler generate electricity by rotating its blades using the forces of nature?

I just tried rotating different coolers and fans I have at home with a 2 volt pocket flashlight lamp attached to the wires, but it wouldn't light up. Then I remembered that there are controllers installed to make fans utilize energy with more efficiency or to help control rotation speed, so I guess that'd be the problem.

Would a simpler design of a fan work both ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DC-powered fans often use a brushless permanent-magnet motor along with some control electronics.  The motor itself could act as a generator, but the electronics generally won't allow any power the motor could generate to escape.  Taking apart such a motor would likely allow one to make a generator, though I doubt it could produce much power.

Mains-powered fans often use a different style of brushless motor which won't work well as a generator unless there's already AC voltage present.  It's sometimes possible to use such motors as generators if one properly connects capacitors between the windings, and ensures that there is no load other than the capacitors until the unit has built up some voltage [residual magnetism in the motor's parts won't produce any significant power, but in the absence of a load it may produce enough to produce voltage to build up a magnetic field which would then be capable of producing significant power.  An interesting feature of motors used this way is that they have a limit to the amount of power they can supply without collapsing the magnetic field; trying to draw more than that will collapse the field and shut everything down.

Answer (score 0):

I have had several turbines.  The scientific problem is that wind energy rises on the CUBE of velocity.  here is twice as much energy at 14 mph as at 12 mph.  So any machinery has an immensely wide range of possible utilization. Also small turbines approach the speed of sound at the tip and get into trouble that way. Larger ones require gearing for both these issues.  Also one may find a direct drive turbine with a preloaded magnetized  generator will produce bursts of power which end up being useless.  Perhaps you are set up to be nominally 48 volt as I am.  You have to rise above 48 volt to get power into storage.  An electrical solution lies in a Buck transformer which clips part of the energy output and stores it in a capacitor until it reaches the correct threshold and then passes it thorough.  These complication quickly defeat the small scale user.

I do not think wind turbines will ever pencil.  Much of the time mine are rotating they are whirring and whining but doing no work at all.